# List of unique lists in java

Tags: java, containers

I need to create a collection of unique collection in java. Could someone please suggest possible containers for the same.

I want to have something like `List<List<int>>` where each each of the list could repeat itself in terms of its contents.

For example if my current state of the parent list is say 
`[ [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [4,5,6] ]` and if I intend to add another list say `[3,4,5]` to it, it should not be duplicated and should not be added.

contains() method of List will work with integers, floats etc, but I am not sure if it will be able to match lists.

Please suggest any other container which could help.

Thanks.

Comment: use **Set** instead of **List**

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably be best off using `Set<List<Integer>>` instead of `List<List<Integer>>`.

The above applied to your example:

```
Set<List<Integer>> uniqueLists = new HashSet<>();
uniqueLists.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
uniqueLists.add(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));
uniqueLists.add(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));

// Now, this won't be added:
uniqueLists.add(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));
```

Be careful when you put a collection inside a set, though. You should not change it again, after you have put it in the set.

Comment: I don't understand. Wont this set still add the second `3, 4, 5` since it's separate object from the first `3, 4, 5`?

Comment: @MattD: `Arrays.ArrayList` implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` based on its contents. Try it.

Comment: What if you add a different order such as 4,3,5?

Comment: @goyalshub1509: That's not the same list as `3,4,5`. If you want them to be the same collection, use sets.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you would be interested to use `Set<Set<Integer>>`.
In case you would like to  maintain the addition order, you can use `LinkedHashSet`.

Your code will be like

```
Set<Set<Integer> uniqueLists = new LinkedHashSet<Set<Integer>>();

uniqueLists.add(new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
```

It would avoid two problems from  using `Set<List<Integer>>`.

1) It would retains addition order of the individual lists

2) It individual list will also not have duplicate integer entries.